# Are there any examples of morphology changes when combining two "word parts", which changes more than prefixes/suffixes/infixes/circumfixes do?

Tags: morphology, affixes

In learning about the Hunspell dictionary format, I came across the paper [Implementation of infixes and circumfixes in the spellcheckers](https://ayaspell.sourceforge.net/doc/infixes_medar_2009.pdf), where they describe an extension to Hunspell for better supporting circumfixes.

[image]

They go on to say:

> The prefix `PFX Y i y-on` Strips ‘i’ from the word begin :
>
> ```
> Istfal => ystfalon
> ```
>
> The suffix `SFX Y a y-on` Strips ‘a’ from the word end :
>
> ```
> mcha => ymchon
> ```
>
> - If the verb needs to have strip from tow side, we can express this by combining circumfixes
> - Istqsa => ystqson
>
> `PFX Y i y-on/S`: strip ‘i' from word begin. `SFX S a 0`: strip ‘a’ from word end.

So they are saying Arabic has this advanced case that Hunspell has a hard time dealing with (it can do it, but at cost of verbosity and number of rules). So they come up with a better system. Which makes me wonder [what else Hunspell can't do](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskComputerScience/comments/17nnt6p/what_are_the_shortcomings_of_hunspell_and_related/) (but that is tangent to this current question).

My question for you is, are there any examples of combining what I'm calling "word parts" (are they "morphemes" technically?), but where combining them results in a complex network of changes in the word *beyond* these categories:

- prefix: Inserting before.
- suffix: Inserting after.
- infix: Inserting something in the middle of a word.
- circumfix: Inserting something around a word.

Is there a 5th category?

- **interwovenfix**? Something like we have `foobar` and `helloworld` and when joined together it becomes `foohelbloworarld`. Does anything close to something like that occur?

Or perhaps another 6th related category:

- **shufflefix**? Where the word parts are scattered and reordered? Like `foobar` and `helloworld` become `forldbarohellowo` or something.

And 7th and 8th categories, which build on top of those last two, but also modify the word parts:

- **interwoven-modify-fix**: `rohelodarvorld` (foo becomes ro, hello becomes helo, bar becomes dar, world becomes vorld, etc.)
- **shuffle-modify-fix**: `halodarrovorld`

In short, does it get anymore complicated than just supporting prefix/suffix/infix/circumfix? If so, what are some of the examples or research to look into?

At some point it becomes hard to tell what the source parts are of the whole word, so at some point we will just say "this is a unit" and has no parts, rather than conjuring up some relation. But it seems to be a blended gradient sort of spectrum thing, not a discrete YES/NO sort of thing where it's clearly one or the other. Not sure.

*I am working on hacking together a simplified spell-checker for a dictionary project across languages, and learning from the highly successful hunspell, which at the same time seems to have several shortcomings. So wondering at some level if hunspell can do everything language needs it to, and this question is just one aspect of that.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even the existence of circumfixes is controversial in linguistics. There are two analyses of Arabic. One is that there are, in the imperfective, both prefixes and suffixes, but there are some dependencies between prefix and suffix, where in some dialects -uun is a non-1st plural subject suffix, ti- is a 2nd person prefix, there is also a 3f subject prefix, and so on. Or, you can have list of 8 circumfixes. There is nothing resembling a consensus on the formal nature of affixation, therefore it is question-begging to decide that a there can't be circumfixes because it requires two morphological operations (prefixing and suffixing).

Infixes are a bit easier, when the infix is shoved inside a root, and we can make a reasonable argument that the root is indeed monomorphemic and composed of /αβγδɛ/ and not /αβγ+δɛ/. Even so, people have been observed saying that object markers in Bantu (which immediately precede the root) are "infixes" because they come between tense-aspect morphemes and the root. The standard analysis of that fact is simply that morphemes are arranged in a specific order, and the object marker happens to go right before the root, and not "inside" of something else. Infixation (of a mora) is one way of accounting for Saami consonant gradation.

There is another kind of "fix" though not widely adopted, that of a "parafix". This is a way of handling reduplication, where you attach a "parafix" such as "σ σ" (a pair of syllables) to a word with some number of syllables, and the syllable-markers of the parafix are parallel to those of the base (which then sets off copying, and eventually sequencing as a prefix or suffix). This figures into Clements' theory of reduplication, which however was not widely adopted.

The concept of "prosodic morphology" is probably most relevant to linguistic ways of talking about less-common kinds of prefixing and suffixing morphology, and that literature would expand the empirical coverage for you.

Answer (score 0):

There could be stem changes: man - men in English, póli-s - póle-ōs  in Ancient Greek,

or even this Japanese example: ame 'rain', kasa 'umbrella', ama-gasa 'umbrella' (note both the vowel change (harmony?) in the first part and the initial consonant lenition in the second part)

or this Mandarin example that reflects an earlier morphological process: yǔ 'rain'(noun) vs. yù 'to rain'(verb, archaic) (Chinese tones develop from lost codas and onset voicing, so this probably developed from an earlier verbal marker which was a coda)

Also, you might like reduplication in Austronesian languages:
(Tagalog) sulat - s< um >ulat - su~sulat - s< um >u~sulat

But what you mentioned is (I would say) next to impossible to find in natural languages, because our mind doesn't just organize mental lexicon in random orderless phonetic representations. Even in Semitic languages, which are known for their non-concatenative morphology, they don't randomly shuffle the sounds, but follow the original order of the root, an example from Amharic:

me-mmar (which is underlyingly me-tmar), t is assimilated to m to avoid increasing sonority consonantal clusters 'to study'

tamar-kuñ 'I studied'

timihir-t bet 'school', bet means house, I'm no expert so I don't know where the h comes from

Note that the order of t-m-r never changes into t-r-m or r-t-m or some other combinations

However, there are phonological changes called metathesis that challenge the order of phonetic units, some happen in syllable levels, some happen in sound, or some in feature levels. But to my knowledge, most of them are sporadic (happening in a few words without affecting the entire lexicon)

Japanese: arata-na 'new' vs. atara-shii 'new' (syllable)

English: three - third (sound) (third historically comes from þridda, thri instead of thir)

PIE > Old Armenian: *dwóh₁ > erku (This one is a regular sound change that turns all PIE *dw into OArm erk. There is no general concensus on how this happens, but a possible and fairly convincing theory is that a feature metathesis happened:
d(alveolar, stop) w(velar, oral sonorant)
r(alveolar, oral sonorant) k(velar, stop))